# I'm having trouble calling a tag to use in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg html which  I want to render using using an ID , I've tried using the following syntax:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Vector_Graphics" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" viewBox="0 0 609.8 379.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 609.8 379.1;" xml:space="preserve">
   <defs>
     <g id="worldMap">
       //svg content
     </g> 
   <defs>
   <use xlink:href="worldMap"/>
</svg>
```

But this doesn't seem to render at all! I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Eventually I want to open the svg as a external file from my HTML. This was just a demo to see if 'use' works.

Here is my fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/Snedden27/5htpdzvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper syntax to call an ID.

```
 <use xlink:href="#worldMap"/>
```

You just forgot your hashtag xP

Comment: I am embarrassed at myself ,ty

Comment: Don't be, happens all the time!